# Display * in table in Ascending order (ASC)

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I want to display my cnumber in ascending order that is 1111111,2222,33333,4444,etc from the sql statement below.

```
   SELECT 
      * 
   FROM 
       BIBLEBOOK 
   INNER JOIN 
       CHAPTER ON (BIBLEBOOK.BIBLEBOOK_Id=CHAPTER.BIBLEBOOK_Id) 
   INNER JOIN 
       VERS ON(CHAPTER.CHAPTER_Id=VERS.CHAPTER_Id) 
   WHERE 
       BIBLEBOOK.bnumber='2' 
   ORDER BY
       cnumber ASC;*
```

But when i ran the sql result is

[image]

111111...10101010....111111...12121212....131313....22222222

how can i display the result like 1..2..3..4..5..6..

Answer (score 1):

You can force a numerical sorting when converting your text data type to a numeric one. Use an explicit or this implicit cast

```
 ORDER BY cnumber * 1 ASC
```

Answer (score 1):

Your didn't include any DDLs to describe your tables, but it seems as though your `cnumber` is defined as a `VARCHAR` column, and thus is sorted lexicographically.
If it indeed only contains `NUMERIC` data and is always used as such, it might be a good idea to alter the column's datatype.

If you cannot do that, you can always explicitly cast it in your query so it's sorting numerically.

```
SELECT * 
FROM BIBLEBOOK 
INNER JOIN CHAPTER ON (BIBLEBOOK.BIBLEBOOK_Id=CHAPTER.BIBLEBOOK_Id) 
INNER JOIN VERS ON(CHAPTER.CHAPTER_Id=VERS.CHAPTER_Id) 
WHERE BIBLEBOOK.bnumber='2' 
ORDER BY CAST (cnumber AS NUMERIC) ASC;
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your `cnumber` is set to be text instead of numeric. Try using `CONVERT` function to force the ordering happen using standard number comparison instead of text one:

```
ORDER BY
    CONVERT(cnumber, INTEGER) ASC;*
```

But I would start from considering your column data type change. Why is it set to be text when it handles numeric data on the first place?